# Rotating 2 or More Images Individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, rotatetransform

I desperately need to figure out how to be able to rotate 2 items (images, texts, etc.) on a page individually (e.g. NOT at the same time).  Here's an example of what I'm talking about, but on this page, there is only 1 item (an image).  When I try to duplicate the image, and then rotate it, both images end up rotating simultaneously:  http://testerski.antaranian.me/

Can someone please, please, please show me the code for having the items rotate on their own?  Thank you!!!

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: @McStretch I tried this code `$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.cc-element').rotatable();
});` and

Comment: @McStretch here's the rest: <span id="body" class="ui-helper-clearfix my-corner-all align-left inline-block"> <div id="arena-container" class="ui-corner-all float-left"> <div id="arena"> <span id="cc-element-1" class="cc-element ui-draggable cc-active" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);" > <img src="http://testerski.antaranian.me/shirt.png" style="height: 197.35365477846602px; width: 265.1019243292827px;" > </span> </div> </div> </span> as well as the code below by @FiveTools. Neither achieve the desired effect. I just really need to get this done yesterday! Please, help!!!!

Comment: Can you edit the question and paste all your code that you're using?  I see a semi-colon in you img tag after the src tag.  There could be a number of reasons why it's not working....i see your link below.  I'll check...

Comment: OffTopic: Why not use a slider to rotate? i think it would work better.

Comment: i don't want to slide words (as in a slideshow?), i want them to be able to rotate/angle.

Comment: @FiveTools, thanks, I look fwd to seeing what you come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in main.js change to:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cc-element-1').rotatable();
    $('#cc-element-2').rotatable();

});
```

add in your html:

```
 <span id="cc-element-2" class="cc-element ui-draggable cc-active" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);" >

          <img src="shirt.png" style="height: 197.35365477846602px; width: 265.1019243292827px;" >
      </span>
```

Should work now.  You should show your code cause i'm making an assumption of what you need to fix.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and the same thing is still happening.  When I go to turn either of the images, they BOTH rotate.  I only want them to rotate individually, that is, when they are clicked on to be rotated.  Here's the updated page:  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11770605/sample2.html

Comment: The jquery element was a class selector - which would match both spans...try the change above - I'm selecting by the id of each span.

Comment: brilliant and bravo to you @FiveTools!  Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you!  I'd vote up if i could but i don't have enough cred yet!!!!